# I want to add 4 circles at different random spots, in a given image (python) but the code does not work after adding one

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I want to add circles at random spots on an image. The code adds the circle to the image

Attached is the code that I tried:

```
img = np.zeros([100,100],dtype=np.uint8)
img.fill(20)



def createCircle(width,height , rad ):
  w = random.randint(1, height)
  h = random.randint(1, height)
  center = [int(w), int(h)]
  radius = rad

  Y, X = np.ogrid[:height, :width]
  dist_from_center = np.sqrt((X - center[0])**2 + (Y-center[1])**2)

  mask = dist_from_center <= radius

  return mask


def addCircle(test_image):
  m = createCircle(width = 100, height = 100 , rad = 8 )
  masked_img = test_image.copy()
  masked_img[~m] = 0
  return masked_img

im = addCircle(test_image=img)
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()

im1 = addCircle(test_image = im)
plt.imshow(im1)
plt.show()
```

When i apply `addCircle` function on the image `img`, it adds the circle to the image but when I apply `addCircle` function to `im` it does not add another circle to the image.

I want to add 4 circles to the same image at random places on the image but as of now I am only able to add one circle, the code doesn't work after that.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with machine learning? I've removed the tag. Please make sure the tags are relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am new to stack overflow, was using this to create synthetic data for a ML problem and hence put ML tag.

Comment: That's fine :) That falls into the broader context of your task, but it's related to your _question at hand_. For your first question, you've made a great job of producing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), though :)

Comment: Although, I'm just getting a completely purple canvas. I think your circle exceeds the boundaries of the frame?

Comment: Your problem seems to be in this line `masked_img[~m] = 0`. Switching it to `masked_img[m] = 0` produces more predictable behavior of four circles showing up, albeit in the negative image.

Comment: Thanks:) When you apply addCircle to img , it does show a circle but when you apply after that, it just shows purple canvas

Comment: The change by @DuPark gives me 2 circles

Comment: @roganjosh, sorry, I changed it to add four circles in a simple for loop at the end of the code that I didn't show in the comment.

Comment: @DuPark sorry from me too, I was trying to say to the OP that you fixed the issue :) You should post as an answer.

Comment: @DuPark thank you.  Solves the problem.

Comment: I have a quick question, is there a way i can add a choice of fill (like sin or cos) to the circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments... Your problem seems to be in this line `masked_img[~m] = 0`.

```
def addCircle(test_image):
    m = createCircle(width = 100, height = 100 , rad = 8 )
    masked_img = test_image.copy()
    masked_img[m] = 0
    return masked_img

# im = addCircle(test_image=img)
# plt.imshow(im)
# plt.show()
for i in range(4):
    img = addCircle(test_image=img)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image: Result]